# Functioning of promise - promise in pending state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I am learning JS and got hit with one of an issue, I am trying to call a service using a function and then over the response I am doing some processing. My expectation is function should return a value instead of the promise. I tried using await/then but none works. Can someone please point out the issue. Below is the snippet of function.

```
    const isDeviceAnExtendedNode = async (deviceId) => {
  getDevicesInfo(deviceId).then(response =>{
    if(response !== undefined){
      response[0].roles.forEach(role => {
        if(roleType.has(role)){
          console.log('has')
          return false;
      }})
    }
  })
}
```

Below is the calling function:

```
export const getFilteredDevices = (deviceList, deviceId, CedgeDeviceList) => {
  const filteredDevices = [];
  deviceList.map((device) => {
    isDeviceAnExtendedNode(device.instanceUuid)
    console.log('hello')
    {
      filteredDevices.push({ text: device.hostname, value: device.instanceUuid });
    }

  });
  return filteredDevices;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: add return before 'getDevicesInfo'  so that the function can return some value

Comment: Even then though, the function *will* always return a promise by definition.

Comment: yes it is returning a promise still, where I am wrong ?

Comment: at function call 'isDeviceAnExtendedNode()' put await

Comment: can you please show the function(isDeviceAnExtendedNode) call ?

Comment: putting await gives an error .... await isDeviceAnExtendedNode(device.instanceUuid)

Comment: await applies only when you are calling it from async function so in map function put async like ```deviceList.map(async(device) => {```

Comment: putting async at map worked ?

Comment: no.. it didn't work

Comment: Have you put return before getDevicesInfo(deviceId) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249802/discussion-between-srushti-shah-and-srishti-tiwari).

Comment: I have made few changes as per your suggestion... added async to getFilteredDevice.. and return in front of getDeviceInfo

Comment: I see now the promise is not getting returned but the return value which is false is not reached to calling function

Comment: I see it goes through the if block but the value is not coming to called function